# What does おなり mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

What does おなり mean in:

> 気持に**おなり**になった

> あと一カ月ぐらいして、もし君が説明してもいいというお気持に**おなり**になったら、そのときは僕たちにご連絡くださいませ、だ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an honorific language pattern お〇〇になる in which 〇〇 is a verb in a continuative form (*ren'youkei*, e.g. お聞きになる, お帰りになる).

The verb in this sentence is なる, thus its continuative form is なり.

Altogether the phrase is equivalent to 気持ちになったら<sup>*</sup> except that in a polite form.

Not sure what the context is (you are likely preparing for something that will happen in a month), but one of the following would probably fit: "If you feel like...", "If you make up your mind to...", "If you feel confident enough to..."

<sup>*</sup>By coincidence the phrase and the fixed pattern use the same verb なる. This なったら uses the verb なる (from おなり) and conditional form of the honorific expression (the other なったら).

Comment: すいません、「This なったら **receives uses** the verb なる」ってどういう意味ですか？それと、 potential form ってどれのことですか？

Comment: 誤変換でした。ありがとう。 potentialはなったらの「たら」

Comment: potentialって「可能形」って意味ですよね・・・(「なれる」とか「行ける」とか。)「たら」って、助動詞「た」の仮定形(hypothetical form)じゃなかったですかね・・

Comment: That's not called "potential" in English? Then how is it called?

Comment: 「なったら」「行ったら」って、(one of) the conditional form(s) ですかね・・(違ったらすいません)

Comment: If you say so... 勉強になりました